# How can I separate WordPress gallery thumbnails into categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

I realize that title is a bit vague, so let me try and clear it up.

I have a project that will be built in WordPress and features a somewhat complex portfolio.  Each piece in the portfolio will be a WordPress post.  Easy.  Then, within each post, there will be thumbnails for each project.  However, I want these thumbnails to be broken up into categories.  So, one project may have 10 total thumbnails.  Four of those should be in displayed in a box called "Digital" and the remaining six in a box called "Film".

Any ideas how I can separate thumbnails?  I am comfortable using WordPress native functionality, or a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best way to do this is using a custom field in the Media Library.  Each uploaded item will be categorized using the Custom Field.  Then when each post is called, the items in the gallery can be called by their custom field.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating two separate galleries for each project.

The NextGen Gallery Plugin makes creating galleries and thumbnails very easy, as well as embedding them.  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

You will be able to put any number of galleries into 1 post.  So, if you need 2 or more groups of thumbnails, you would simply embed each gallery within the post.

Maybe title the galleries ProjectName-Film, ProjectName-Digital, etc. for easy organization.

Comment: Thank you.  I had been considering NGG, but I am not 100% sure that it can accomplish what I need.  The gallery will be laid out with one large image above the thumbnails.  When the thumbnails are clicked, the fullsize then populates the large image.  So, if I had multiple NGG's on the page, it wouldn't be able to populate that same space, as it would be three separate galleries.  If this doesn't make sense, please let me know and I will elaborate or clear it up.

Comment: I see your problem and I am not aware of any Wordpress plugins that will make that easy for you.  I think you would need to custom code the galleries with jQuery.

However, NGG uses Lightbox to show the images.  So they pop out into the larger size.  Not exactly what you are looking for, but would be  easy to separate the thumbnails.

Comment: I figured I would have to build something completely custom, but I was hoping there was something out there that may give me a headstart, haha.  I'm not going to rule NGG out, it just may take some tweaking.  Thanks so much for your help, and taking the time to reply!